# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' in for loop

Tags: python, twitter, data-analysis

I keep getting the following error in my code:

```
itb.split(" ")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

My code is as follows:

```
itb = load_data(input("Please enter the name of your data file: ").lower())

for i in itb:
if "://" in i[1] and '2015-11-16' == i[2][:10]:
    itb.split(" ")
    print (i[1])
```

Any insight in how to fix this would be great!

Comment: Why do you want to [**`split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) `itb` if it's a `list` and not a `str`?

Comment: We can't fix this unless you give us some idea what your desired output is. Did you mean to call `i.split(" ")` instead?

Comment: I want to split itb because I am supposed to extract a web link from a tweet. My desired output would be for the code to find the most popular link and count how many times it appeared.

Comment: At the end of the day, you can't split a list (unless you create your own function for doing so). You must be meaning to split one of the values contained within `i`. It seems that even `i` is a list.